Debug multiple sessions in flutter
I have web app and I need to debug login behavior for several users.
I'm starting a project by pressing F5, chrome is opened it's session for user1 all good and clear. Than I'm opening new Chrome instance in incognito and pasting localhost:port from browser which was opened by VsCode for user1.
I'm setting breakpoint and starting to login as user2, but none of breakpoints ever trigger...
so my question is how I can debug 2nd user behavior locally, thx in advance
